# how to increase delay for DoubleTapped event of a button in C# for windows 8?

Tags: c#, windows-8

I have to handle some event while double tapping on a button how to increase a delay between first tap and second tap on the mouse in C#

Comment: is this something that you really need or something you are really trying to prevent..?? be more specific as to what you are looking to truly accomplish.

Comment: That is a system setting.  If you want to change it you will probably have to watch for the tapped event twice and then measure the time between them.

Comment: What technology are you using, WinRT or desktop (classic .net)?  If classic, WinForms, or WPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have that same scenario solved in javascript. You can find my writeup here... http://slickthought.net/post/2012/06/08/Handling-Click-DoubleClick-in-Windows-8-Metro-JavaScript.aspx

You will have to replace the Promises with something like a Task so its not a 1:1 match, but it will give you the right idea on how to solve the issue.